# How do you created a nested form using HTML::FormHandler in Catalyst?

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have a situation where we have a base recordset with about one hundred thousand records. And, we are creating a separate application that shares some of the dataset, but not most, so we are creating a detail table that has a one to one relationship with the original table. What I want to do is pull the existing information from the original table and display it as read only, but I want the fields in the detail table to be writeable.

I've started by creating a listing with the contents of the original table, I want the user to be able to seemlessly hit "edit" by an entry and be taken to the form to create the detail record, click save, and have it update, or create the record.

So, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a real answer, in that I can't really provide you with a solution, but I can hopefully provide you with somewhere to start.  I think you need to define a form in HTML::FormHandler which represents a single row from your detail table, then build your read-only form from multiple instances of single-row form.  This article describes the problem and a partial solution much better than I have:

http://catdev.blogspot.com/2009/05/defining-form-processing-problem.html

I'm fairly new to Perl and HTML::FormHandler, and there's a good chance that there is a better way of doing this.  It's a problem that I have solved 'manually' in PHP before, but one which I am sure I will come across in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but in order to help future searchers...

Including a related table in a form is handled automatically if your DBIx::Class result sources are correctly setup. A related table can be pulled into the form by simply defining a compound field using the relationship name of the other field and defining subfields with the names of the columns in the related table.

See: [HTML::FormHandler::Manual::Fields](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormHandler%3a%3aManual%3a%3aFields#Compound)

And: [HTML::FormHandler::Manual::Database](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aFormHandler%3a%3aManual%3a%3aDatabase)